# Prevent Twilio SMS Instant-Auto-Response "OK"

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a Twilio integration setup with an application I am building. The application allows users to send and receive text messages to/from a Twilio phone number.

For example, assume you're a user. When you create an account, you receive a phone number -- this phone number is purchased and managed via Twilio. You can then use this phone number to send and receive regular text messages.

To send, it's easy, just make the Twilio API call.

To receive, I'm using the webhook integrations. Meaning, I have a hosted server at `https://my-website.com/api/sms/receive`. Any time some external person sends a text message to the Twilio phone number, Twilio will send a HTTP POST request to my server.

**The problem:** Twilio is auto-responding, immediately, to the external persons phone number with `OK`. I cannot find any documentation about how to prevent this from happening.

I'll provide a real-world use case as an example.

Say *Bob* is a user of my application. *Bob* have a Twilio phone number through my app. *Bob* wants to send a text message to *Alice*. *Alice* is **not** a user of the app -- they're just some external person. *Bob* is using the app to communication with *Alice* via *Alice's* normal phone number.

1. *Bob* sends a text to *Alice* via the Twilio integration
2. *Alice* receives the text message on their phone
3. *Alice* responds back to *Bob's* text
4. Twilio triggers my server webhook integration
5. Twilio immediately auto-responds back to *Alice* with `OK`

**(5.) is the problem -- I don't want this to happen**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Turns out the webhook API needs to use the TwiML (Twilio Markdown Language) to instruct Twilio not to respond. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-without-Responding

Specifically, my server just returns a `Content-Type` of `text/html` and the body is simply `<Response></Response>`